# Issue in generating the Release APK in Visual Studio for Xamarin.Form Application

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, apk

I am working on `Xamarin.Form` application(Android and iOS). Want to generate the APK file in release mode to upload into the Google Play store.

I have followed the instruction of [this Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/publishing/publishing-to-google-play/index?tabs=windows) article & getting below `Exception`

> Google Play Store: Authorize:  The type initializer for
>   'Google.Apis.Json.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer' threw an exception

I have already tried following things

- Clean my entire solution.
- Deleted and re-added the *Newtonsoft.Json package*(tried with both an older version and new versions)
- Added the *Newtonsoft.Json* dll in Skip linking
  assemblies under Android Options in Properties.

Please Check this

[image]

Comment: What version of Visual studio are you using? You supposed to use 15.8 or newer.

Comment: update to VS2017 15.9, this fixed the issue.

Comment: Am using 5.7.3 version

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you should be able to make an ad-hoc .APK and upload that to Google Play.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_3-_publishing_an_application_on_google_play/manually-uploading-the-apk/

I would advise to upgrade Visual Studio, since many problems reported referred to an older version.